# What are the bare minimum security configuration recommendations when using Windows Server to hosts websites

Tags: windows, web-hosting

I am using Windows Server 2003 to host a few websites.  I have the Windows Firewall enabled along with Remote Desktop and FTP. I am considering installing AVG Free for basic protection.  Is this enough?  Should i install anti virus on my production server?

Can anyone give any tips on bare minimum standard security setup?

Answer (score 2):

The [Security Compliance Toolkit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc163140.aspx) will probably help you out a lot in getting your security up to par.